# JQuery UI and RequireJS are mapping widgets incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js, requirejs

I'm using [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org) to load [Knockout Sortable](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable) (v1.10), which has [jquery-ui](https://jqueryui.com) (v1.12) as a dependency. Both of these were added through bower and placed in my require config. However, I'm having some strange issues with require incorrectly fetching the path for some of the widgets.

My path looks like this for jquery-ui:

```
paths: {
    ...
    'jquery-ui': '/lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui',
    ...
    // or the .min version like below:
    // 'jquery-ui': '/lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min',
}
```

The jquery-ui stuff loads without any issues, but the components go crazy. My console log looks something like this:

```
GET http://localhost:5000/lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/draggable.js net::ERR_ABORTED    
require.min.js:5 Uncaught Error: Script error for "jquery-ui/ui/widgets/draggable", needed by: knockout-sortable
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at l (require.min.js:5)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.min.js:5)
```

I get this same error for 3 separate widgets. The widgets are located at `/lib/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/*.js`, but RequireJS is prepending a second `jquery-ui` directory.

The Knockout Sortable is requesting the resources like so:

```
require("jquery-ui/ui/widgets/sortable");
require("jquery-ui/ui/widgets/draggable");
require("jquery-ui/ui/widgets/droppable");
```

I've tried all manners of shimming and mapping, and nothing really seems to work, and so I'm at a bit of a loss.

Also of note, if I use jquery-ui.min, the path's turn into:

```
http://localhost:5000/lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min/ui/widgets/*.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more tinkering, I figured out I needed to slightly modify my path's as follows:

```
paths: {
    ...
    'jquery-ui': ['/lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min'],
    'jquery-ui/ui': ['/lib/jquery-ui/ui'],
    ...
}
```

It turns out that the slightly more specific version of the definition allows me to override the weird behavior that was occurring. The issue was compounded two fold as I was using another package called NestedSortable. This package had not been updated to deal with jQuery UI 1.12+'s new folder structures. So I had to fork that repo and create a new bower package.